# FreeBSD centralized build server

Tags: build, freebsd, binaries, centralized

Up front: I am not a system adminstrator and my knowledge of FreeBSD-administration is targeted towards getting the programs I have written running.

I've started out with a single FreeBSD machine. Now I've got four up and running. From the start I've used the ports tree for installations.

I'd love to run something like a centralized build and distribution system. There must be some professional term for such a thing, but I seriously don't know. If I would, I would propably be able to find the right infomation.

And that's the question: how (i.e. which tools and/or processes does it take) can I build and distribute FreeBSD binaries from a centralized system?

Comment: ======= `poudriere` ======= And `pkg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use something like `poudriere` or `tinderbox` to manage your build environments. You should be doing parallel builds; `distcc` allows you to do simple distributed builds and `ccache` provides a speed-up by caching results.

Once you get the builds working, you just need to export the generated packages.

Here's a how-to for `poudriere`: https://github.com/freebsd/poudriere/wiki/pkg_repos